# Xorg: two different libglx.so's with two different serverlayouts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, xorg

I have an nvidia card for on monitor and a radeon (onboard) card for a second screen on Ubuntu 11.04.

Would it be possible to have one serverlayout use the nvidia libglx.so and the second serverlayout use the default xorg libglx.so?

Here's my xorg.conf at the moment: http://pastie.org/1962509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the question of which libglx.so is loaded by applications is determined by your shell environment, not by the X server itself (this makes sense when you consider that X11 was designed to be able to display applications running on a remote machine).

So, assuming that your xorg `libglx.so` is under `/usr/X11R6/lib` and that for your nvidia cards is under `/usr/X11R6/lib/nvidia` then you can do:

```
# for the nvidia drivers
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/X11R6/lib/nvidia quake3
# for the Radeon version:
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/X11R6/lib quake3
```

But that said, my reading of your X11 configuration states that you're not using Xinerama, but instead using separate screens that you (AFAICS) migrate windows between. Assuming that's true, then you won't have a problem.

Otherwise, I can potentially imagine a great deal of confusion happening when an an application which has the radeon glx drivers loaded starts up on the nvidia head.

Comment: Thanks. That pointed me in the right direction. I'm using the second screen for running an instance of xbmc on my tv downstairs.

I'm now using this:
`sudo update-alternatives --set gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf && sudo startx /root/xinitrc_xbmc -- :1 -nolisten tcp -novtswitch -sharevts -layout hdmi3`